# Unzipping Files with a large amount of small Files inside

Tags: java, android, zip, extract

I have a lot of zips with a large amount of Files which i have to unzip to the SD-Card.

Currently I am using the `util.zip` Package with `Zipentry` for each File inside the zips. This works fine but is very slow.

So I wonder if there is a lib which can handle those Files faster than the normal zip of Java/Android.

Edit: The zips are archives which are about 5 to 10MB large and contain about 50 to 100 jpg-Files whiche are each part of a picture. I need to extract all zips to a specific folder.
Slow means that the same files are extracted on an IPhone in fraction of the time.

Edit 2 the code:

```
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fd);
    ZipEntry ze = null;
    while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Unzipping " + ze.getName());

    if (ze.isDirectory()) {
        File f = new File(targetFilePath + ze.getName());

        if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
        }
    } else {
        int size;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath + ze.getName() + ".tile");
        BufferedOutputStream bufferOut = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream, buffer.length);

        while ((size = zin.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        bufferOut.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }

        bufferOut.flush();
        bufferOut.close();
    }
    }
    zin.close();
```

Comment: Please give examples on what "large amount of Files" and "is very slow" mean.

Comment: Hi LUkas I edited my Question, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best case you could do is go NDK way. AFAIK, Google even provides supported headers/API in NDK on zlib.